# How can I improve PyODBC performance of a single row select (i.e. a lookup)?

Tags: python, pyodbc

I want to improve the performance of an SQL Select call via ODBC/pyODBC.

This is not against a large database (maybe 10K rows), pulling a unique record (15 columns) from the table.  The combined size of the 15 columns is about 500 bytes). I'm using `pyODBC`, and using `fetchone`, the fastest I have been able to get it down to is about 2 seconds. It used to be roughly 3.5 seconds. I've set the encoding and decoding to UTF-8 to match the database. I have confirmed that the transaction level is read_uncommitted.

I am using DataDirect ODBC driver on Unbuntu Linux.

I can't seem to get it below 2 seconds, but if I run it from a SQL processor (like db visualizer, or dbeaver) the row returns in 0.3 to 0.4 seconds.  It's a very simple query with one where clause that uniquely indexed.  No wild cards, no exists, etc.

Is this just a minimum amount of time that `pyodbc` takes to process a query?

```py
query = 'select order_num, pick_ticket_num, package_id, ship_via, name, contact, address1, address2, address3, city, state, postal_code, country, phone from dbc.v_dmv5 where package_id = ?'  

cursor.execute(query, sqlArgs)
row = cursor.fetchone()
```

I also tried using `turbodbc` which results in the same performance level of about 2s for the query. But running this exact query in any sql processor is essentially immediate.

It's definitely not the parameterization field either since I've actually hard coded a value in to the where clause, and it still takes 2+ seconds to execute.

Comment: You've already tried turbodbc and gotten similar results, suggesting that it's the ODBC driver that's slow. You could also try creating an ODBC DSN and using the `isql` utility as another point of comparison that is completely outside of Python.

Comment: Thats a great idea.  I just ran it isql which uses the same odbc driver.  So it gets even more interesting.  If you run it in iSQL - the result for the data comes back instantaneously  - like immediately shows up.  But the cursor doesnt come back for another 2 seconds.   So it seems like maybe the driver is holding the connection open for about those two seconds until it cleans up and is done ???  Which is what PyODBC is responding to.     Is there any way to speed up the odbc driver to come back and just be done with the execution ?

Comment: So if you open a cursor and then run (execute, fetchall) the query three times in a tight loop on that same open cursor does the test take ~6 seconds or is it more like ~3 seconds?

Comment: its only one record, so I run fetchone.  But if I look fetchone 3x from execute to fetch, it literally is 2s, 2s, 2s so 6s.  Enclosed is timestamp for 3 runs


2020-08-14 18:34:08,808- dmv5 -  INFO :
2020-08-14 18:34:10,771- dmv5 -  INFO :
2020-08-14 18:34:12,727- dmv5 -  INFO :

Comment: And here it is if its changed out to fetchall.  .  
2020-08-14 18:40:12,176- dmv5 -  INFO 
2020-08-14 18:40:14,027- dmv5 -  INFO 
2020-08-14 18:40:16,044- dmv5 -  INFO

Answer (score 0):

Based on the discussion in the comments to the question, especially

> If you run it in iSQL - the result for the data comes back instantaneously - like immediately shows up. But the cursor doesnt come back for another 2 seconds.

and

> But if I look fetchone 3x from execute to fetch, it literally is 2s, 2s, 2s

it appears that the driver retrieves the last value in the last row, for example ...

```
so63171038      27b8-1b2c   EXIT  SQLGetData  with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
        HSTMT               0x000000997E788440
        UWORD                        2 
        SWORD                       -8 <SQL_C_WCHAR>
        PTR                 0x00000099746BD0A0 [       6] "bar"
        SQLLEN                  4096
        SQLLEN *            0x00000099722EE380 (6)
```

... and then when it calls `SQLFetch` again to see if there is more information to retrieve (and there isn't) ...

```
so63171038      27b8-1b2c   ENTER SQLFetch 
        HSTMT               0x000000997E788440

so63171038      27b8-1b2c   EXIT  SQLFetch  with return code 100 (SQL_NO_DATA_FOUND)
        HSTMT               0x000000997E788440
```

... that's what is introducing the ~2 second delay.

It definitely looks like a driver (or perhaps database) issue to me.

Comment: Thank you for that tip and explanation.  It is definitely returning the data quickly, but not releasing, so still fetching like you said or going back.  Its a datadirect/Progress ODBC driver so its /supposed/ to be a decent one. . lol   But it seems no matter what query you run and optimize, the minimum is a 2s sunken cost or something. . .

Comment: is this something that is normal with ODBC drivers ?  it doesnt seem to happen on JDBC drivers and wondering how to go about this - contact Progress/DataDirect I guess.  It seems to be an issue for any query that has a join in it.  Have to narrow it down further with odbc traces.

Comment: This particular behaviour is not one that I've seen displayed by any ODBC driver that I have encountered, and I've worked with some pretty dodgy ones. So yes, I would consider reporting the issue to the driver vendor. Be sure to mention the join aspect and, as always, it would be best if you could provide them with a [mcve] .

Comment: Yeah Im at a loss.  Not sure if DataDirect will listen since I dont think I have an ongoing mainteannce plan with them.  But the difference  is significant.  JDBC driver is showing 0.051 and 0.0123sec for running the query (prepare and execute).    ODBC is showing 2.1 seconds for the two combined.  So the difference is significant for the exact same query

Comment: definitely a driver issue.  Driver version 7.16.0175 (which is what I'm using exhibits this behavior.  Driver version 7.6.0198 does not exhibit this behavior and comes back immediately.